# Why I got NaN when computing volatility?

Tags: python, pandas, volatility

I am trying to follow the equations on this paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030142150700153X?casa_token=LH4pYGk9HHAAAAAA:ftNaTD1y7vFvFsxUxR3L9GUUVjfnnNSFWjVXp9Q9R7UdJLvaWgEDfMgqouuxa9HlnpUjgs3BKg) , to calculate the historical volatility for power time series data.

The statistical description of the data as follows :

```
count    9855.000000
mean      291.135088
std       187.503344
min         0.000000
25%       112.408512
50%       332.370871
75%       449.527323
max       601.370058
```

Here is my implementation:

```
# Computing Volatility
window_size=27
VOLATILITY = pd.DataFrame()
VOLATILITY['PV']= data
#'intra-hour
# Compute the logarithmic value  
VOLATILITY['Log_IA'] = np.log(VOLATILITY['PV'] / VOLATILITY['PV'].shift(1))
# Compute Volatility using the pandas rolling standard deviation function
VOLATILITY['intra-hour'] = VOLATILITY['Log_IA'].rolling(window=window_size).std() * np.sqrt(window_size)# *100
```

My data have 1 year of half-hourly observations for 27 steps for each day

Here is an example of the output I got for 1 selected day where the NaN problem exists

```
    
Timestamp           PV          Log_IA     intra-hour
2019-03-01 06:00:00 0.000000    NaN         NaN
2019-03-01 06:30:00 2.946333    inf         NaN
2019-03-01 07:00:00 20.963667   1.962229    NaN
2019-03-01 07:30:00 38.284333   0.602250    NaN
2019-03-01 08:00:00 38.224667   -0.001560   NaN
2019-03-01 08:30:00 54.486667   0.354475    NaN
2019-03-01 09:00:00 54.608333   0.002230    NaN
2019-03-01 09:30:00 55.290667   0.012418    NaN
2019-03-01 10:00:00 54.317333   -0.017761   NaN
2019-03-01 10:30:00 54.680333   0.006661    NaN
2019-03-01 11:00:00 42.142333   -0.260451   NaN
2019-03-01 11:30:00 44.569000   0.055986    NaN
2019-03-01 12:00:00 36.988333   -0.186436   NaN
2019-03-01 12:30:00 35.802000   -0.032599   NaN
2019-03-01 13:00:00 29.006667   -0.210478   NaN
2019-03-01 13:30:00 43.254333   0.399572    NaN
2019-03-01 14:00:00 45.246333   0.045024    NaN
2019-03-01 14:30:00 29.768333   -0.418676   NaN
2019-03-01 15:00:00 37.510667   0.231180    NaN
2019-03-01 15:30:00 31.937000   -0.160860   NaN
2019-03-01 16:00:00 39.990333   0.224873    NaN
2019-03-01 16:30:00 32.263000   -0.214717   NaN
2019-03-01 17:00:00 40.707333   0.232487    NaN
2019-03-01 17:30:00 14.551333   -1.028726   NaN
2019-03-01 18:00:00 10.294333   -0.346089   NaN
2019-03-01 18:30:00 2.552667    -1.394455   NaN
2019-03-01 19:00:00 0.036333    -4.252158   NaN
```

So, why I am getting the NaN as a result for volatility ?

is it a problem with my implementation?

Comment: Can you provide toy data?

Comment: https://filebin.net/sqc2jv6ahowkph9n

Comment: Is the inf of 2019/03/01 6:30 affected by the output results?

Comment: Yes it's the inf is a result of the logarithmic calculation

VOLATILITY['Log_IA'] = np.log(VOLATILITY['PV'] / VOLATILITY['PV'].shift(1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is such that you will always get `NaN` for the zeroth value of `Log_IA` regardless of the values of `PV`. This is a result of the shift and can be confirmed by running the following snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


VOLATILITY = pd.DataFrame()
VOLATILITY['PV'] = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
VOLATILITY['Log_IA'] = np.log(VOLATILITY['PV'] / VOLATILITY['PV'].shift(1))
```

You will see that `VOLATILITY` is:

```
    PV    Log_IA
0  1.0       NaN
1  2.0  0.693147
2  3.0  0.405465
```

The zeroth value of `Log_IA` is `NaN` because you are dividing [image: \log{1.0}] by the previous value of `PV`, that is the value of `PV` at index -1. This is what `shift()` does, but there is no value at index -1 so you get a `NaN`. You may set a value to use in place of any non-existent values with the `fill_value` argument: `shift(1, fill_value=123)`. You will also get `inf` for any value of `Log_IA` when the previous index's `PV` value is 0.

So why do you get `NaN`s for all values of `intra-hour`? You take the rolling standard deviation of `VOLATILITY['Log_IA'].rolling(window=window_size)` which contains `inf` at index 0, and standard deviation is undefined for sequences containing `inf`. So the rolling standard deviation is `NaN`, and any arithmetic operation with `NaN` results in `NaN`.

Now, you also have an issue with [image: \log{0}] in your code. Logarithm is undefined for values less than or equal to 0, but this is not what is causing your `NaN`s.

https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/logarithmic-functions.html